# Ruby on rails display many records in a table in one html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am now working on a job-listing project with ruby on rails. I have create a model called `job` which records the job on the list and a controller called `jobs` to control the actions. And each job belongs to a category, such as IT, Finance etc. I want to add a button for the user to select, for example the jobs of IT field. I have tried

```
rails g controller it/jobs
```

In the `it_jobs_controller`

```
def index
   @jobs = Job.where(:field => "IT")
end
```

The above works well.
I have also tried, in `jobs` controller, to add a method

```
def get_it
    @jobs = Job.where(:field => "IT")
end
```

And in `config/routes`

```
resources :jobs do
    member do
        get :get_it
    end
end
```

But it seems that I need to add `params[:id]` to link to that page, but that is not what I want.
Could anyone tell me how to add a page like `index` page, but not to create a new `controller`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to use:

```
resources :jobs do
    collection do
        get :get_it
    end
end
```

The route would then be `jobs/get_it`.

Also, to debug such issues have a look at the output of `rails routes` (issue this command in the console).

If you want to have a custom route (like `it/jobs`), this can be done like this:

```
get `it/jobs` => "jobs#get_it"
```

Comment: Yes perfect, that is what I want! Thank you very much!

Comment: Could I ask where to put `get \`it/jobs\` => "jobs#get_it"`

Comment: why don't you address grave misconceptions of rails? Having an own action  for every category instead of using parameters? That is just *wrong*

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement you should add one more model `Category`

The association would app/models/category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :jobs
end
```

app/models/job.rb

```
class Jon < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :category
end
```

config/routes.rb

```
resources :categories do
  resources :jobs, on: :member
end
```

In this way you can create multiple jobs inside one category.
If you can query please let me know.

Comment: Yes I could query as you figured out. Thank you!

Comment: everything you included in your answer the OP has already achieved